# Google Sheets Script for openByUrl, with a URL from a list (Loop for the URL)

Tags: loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here is the intent.

I have a Parent sheet (represented by URL [www.AAAA.aaa](http://www.AAAA.aaa)).  On it is a tab called "race".  I have made 5 copies of this spreadsheet, and the URLs to these copies are listed in a spreadsheet represented by URL [www.BBBB.bbb](http://www.BBBB.bbb), in a tab called PLAYERS, in the range G2:G20.

I will be making frequent updates to my Parent sheet, in the "race" tab, in the range of L8:L103.

Instead of having to open each of the 5 copies, and pasting the corrections/changes, I am designing this script to:

1. Fetch the values and formulas from [www.AAAA.aaa](http://www.AAAA.aaa) > "race" > L8:L103
2. Fetch the list of URLS from [www.BBBB.bbb](http://www.BBBB.bbb) > "PLAYERS" > G2:G20
3. And paste it over the "race" > L8:L103 in each of the spreadsheets listed in the PLAYERS tab.

(NOTE: There will eventually be hundreds of sheets, but for this example, I only have 5).

In essence, this script will help me "push" corrections to any errors I may have made in the original Parent sheet to each of the copies.

At first, I tried copyTo (to replace the whole sheet, instead of just range L8:L103), but when it deleted the old "race" tab, it broke several data validations that were pointing to the "race" tab.  No matter what I tried with copyTo, it always broke something by deleting the old "race" tab.

Here is what I have so far...

```
function copyValuesAndFormulasBetweenSpreadsheets() {
  // Source information
  const sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("www.AAAA.aaa");
  const sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("race");
  const sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange("L8:L103");
  const values = sourceRange.getValues();
  const formulas = sourceRange.getFormulas();
  const urlSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("www.BBBB.bbb");
  const urlSheet = urlSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("PLAYERS");
  var urls = urlSheet.getRange("G2:G20").getValues();

  // Destination information
for (let u = 0; u<urls.length; u++) {
  var destinationSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(urls[u][0]);  //THIS IS WHERE I'M GETTING AN ERROR OF Exception: Invalid argument: url
  const destinationSheet = destinationSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("race")
  const range = destinationSheet.getRange("L8:L103");
  range.setValues(values);
  for (let i = 0; i < formulas.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < formulas[i].length; j++) {
      if (formulas[i][j]) {
        range.getCell(i+1, j+1).setFormula(formulas[i][j]);
      }
    }
  }
}
}
```

I am getting the error "Exception: Invalid argument: url" on line 14...

There are two loops (one, that isn't working, is the "Loop through the list of URLs and make the changes).  The second loop is to paste both values and formulas.  setValues doesn't work right if there are both values and formulas, and setFormulas has the same issue.  So, I had to use this solution, as I needed the values to copy over as values, and the formulas to copy over as formulas.  This works just fine when I am updating a single, defined URL without a loop.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out...  Script is fine...

After running the console.log that Yuri tested, it pulled the list fine...  Except, it was also pulling blank cells...

The range in my script for URLs was G2:G20, however, I currently only had G2:G6 filled with URLs.  The error that was being produced was because of the blank cells.

I modified the range to G2:G6, and it ran fine.

Comment: Btw, you can remove empty elemnts from your array this way: `var urls = urlSheet.getRange("G2:G20").getValues().flat().filter(String);` But this will be a flat 1d array. You need to call its values as `urls[u]` instead of `urls[u][0]`

Comment: I ended up using   const urlSheet = urlSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("PLAYERS");
  var urls = urlSheet.getRange("G3:G").getValues();
  var filteredUrls = urls.filter(String);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

Comment: This solution helped me solve my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Probably you forgot the slash `/` at the end of these URLs.

It should be:

```
www.AAAA.aaa/ 
www.BBBB.bbb/
```

or `/edit`

```
www.AAAA.aaa/edit
www.BBBB.bbb/edit
```

or `/edit#gid=` + some number

```
www.AAAA.aaa/edit#gid=123
www.BBBB.bbb/edit#gid=456
```

Just in case. I've tried to recreate the algorithm and it gets no error with my list or URLs:

```
function open_by_url() {
  var urls = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1:A3").getValues();
  console.log(urls)
  for (var i in urls) {
    var url = urls[i][0];
    console.log(url);
    var s = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
    console.log(s.getName());
  }
}
```

The list or my URLs looks like this:

[image]

The snippet successfully reads the URLs from the list, opens the spreadsheets and prints its names in console.

Actually, for this case I'd probably prefer `(... of ...)` variant of loop `for`:

```
for (let url of urls) { 
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  // do stuff
}
```

But it doesn't matter.

Comment: Yes, those were just example URLs, and not the actual URLs...  I changed the actual URLs to those made up examples for this post.

Comment: Check your actual urls. Do they have slashes `/` at the end?

Comment: Here's the end of the URL...   sXWUBHpG5gp0Co/edit#gid=0

Comment: Ok. Then, we can exclude this suspect from the case.

Comment: Try to add `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` after `var urls = urlSheet.getRange("G2:G20").getValues()`. But I still believe that there is some error in your range. I've tried about the same algorithm and wasn't able to reproduce the error with my list of URLs.

Comment: To test, I ran the console.log() on the same list, and it logged them properly.  Then, I substituted the code for just one specific URL, taken from the same list, and it worked.  I don't think it is a problem with the URL itself in the file, because when I run them individually, they work.  I added in the SpreadsheetApp.flush() ; with no change.